# Why 'true' and 'TRUE' in Eclipse for PHP?

Tags: php, eclipse

The Eclipse 'intellisense' for some methods in PHP files suggests `true`, looking like the PHP boolean literal, but for other methods suggests `TRUE`, which looks like a constant defined somewhere. What causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what causes it, but both are equivalent. According to the PHP docs:

> To specify a boolean literal, use the keywords TRUE or FALSE. Both are
>   case-insensitive.

Were I to hazard a guess as to the cause, I would think it is just due to many additions to the Eclipse's 'Intellisense' over the years, with various programmers using their own personal preference.

If you want to follow the [PSR-2 standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md), they must be in lower case.

Comment: Thanks. That standard document is the kind of stuff I love; and especially - seems to me - needed in the PHP world.

Comment: @ProfK, I couldn't agree more it would certainly help readability.